# Picture in flask doesn't load into the path

Tags: python, image, file, flask

I'm developing that web app with flask but when I do the upload of the picture, the picture doesn't load without giving any error.
Can you help me please?

web app path:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVeM8.png

Flask form:

```
class UpdateAccountForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    picture = FileField('Carica l\'immagine di profilo', validators=[FileAllowed(['png','jpg'])])
    submit = SubmitField('Aggiorna')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        if email.data != current_user.email:
            user = Account.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
            if user is not None:
                raise ValidationError("Email già utilizzata.")
```

HTML form:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">    
        {{ form.email() }}
        <label class="control-label" for="input">Email</label><i class="mtrl-select"></i>
        {% for error in form.email.errors %}
        <span style="color: red";> {{ error }} </span>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        {{ form.picture.label() }}
        {{ form.picture() }}
        {% for error in form.picture.errors %}
        <span style="color: red";> {{ error }} </span>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="submit-btns">
        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-info") }}
    </div>
    </form>
```

Uploading script:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.picture.data:
            pic = form.picture.data
            picname = secure_filename(pic.filename)
            pic_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/profile_pics')
            pic.save(pic_path + picname)
            current_user.image_file = picname
        current_user.email = form.email.data
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('account'))
```

Comment: Plase include the full traceback which you are receiving.

Comment: I don't get any traceback and any error.

Comment: You need to clarify what's meant by 'doesn't load'.  Have you checked the db to ensure the correct string is saved in `image_file`.  Are you referring to the image not being saved on disk?  Also `pic.save(pic_path + picname)` should probably be `pic.save(os.path.join(pic_path + picname))`. At present it looks like you'll end up saving to: `/rootpath/static/profile_picsIMAGE.JPG` without the slash between `static/profle_pics` and the value of `picname`.

Comment: I fixed like that `if form.pic.data:
            picname = secure_filename(form.pic.data.filename)
            pic_path = os.path.join(app.root_path + 'static/profile_pics/' + picname)
            form.pic.data.save(os.path.join(pic_path))
            current_user.image_file = picname
        current_user.email = form.email.data
        db.session.commit()`
how you said... but it still doesn't work, and in the database the field is correct but it doesn't change the value

Comment: Solved... I missed {{ form.hidden_tag() }} in the html page after the form tag, thank you anyway